# Adding page to the repeated quotation in Historische Zeitschrift Style

Tags: biblatex

Does anyone know how to customise Historische-Zeitschrift Style to make it quote the page where the first occurrence appears instead just the footnote number?

This is how the default quote looks like now:

> See Ath., Ar. 1 (wie Anm. 1), S. 11.

and this is what I need to have:

> See Ath., Ar. 1 (wie Anm. 1, S. 1), S. 11.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{athanasius1998,
    Address = {Berlin/New York},
    Author = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
    Booktitle = {Athanasius Werke - Die dogmatischen Schriften},
    Call-Number = {TH: Vb 17.02-1.1.2},
    Date-Added = {2010-10-16 13:24:30 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-13 17:12:32 +0000},
    Editor = {Marin Tetz and others},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {109-175},
    Publisher = {Walter de Gruyter},
    Read = {No},
    Series = {Urkunden zur Geschichte des Arianischen Streites 318-328},
    Shortauthor = {Ath.},
    Shorttitle = {Ar. 1},
    Title = {Oratio I contra Arianos},
    Volume = {1, Tl. 1, Lfg. 2},
    Year = {1998}}
@incollection{evagrius2011,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Evagrius Scholasticus}},
    Booktitle = {{\'E}vagre Le Scholastique: Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique - Livres I-III},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va1.05/542},
    Date-Added = {2013-08-24 12:11:20 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:31 +0000},
    Editor = {Joseph Bidez and Leon Parmentier},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {Evagr.},
    Shorttitle = {h.e.},
    Title = {Historia ecclesiastica},
    Volume = {542},
    Year = {2011}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
%
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx@loccit}%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx@seenote}% NEW!
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:ibid}}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:note}}}
       {\usebibmacro{footcite:shorthand}}}
       {\iffieldundef{usera}
         {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}}{\printnames{author}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{title}\isdot%
         {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \usebibmacro{in:}%
          \printfield{usera}%
          \setunit*{\addspace}%
          \printfield[default]{volume}}}}
     \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{athanasius1998}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 22]{evagrius2011}
\pagebreak
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 11]{athanasius1998}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{evagrius2011}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Could we have a minimal working example that shows which commands are used for this?

Comment: Of course, I edited my original post to add one. Thanks!

Comment: Please note that you should add a `%` after `\printfield[default]{volume}}}}` to get rid of a spurious white space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by modifying two macros: `footcite:note` and `footcite:save`.

Essentially we replicate the behaviour of the style saving the `note` number in saving the page number `\csxdef{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}{\thepage}%` We can then print the page number after the note number via

```
\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
\@nameuse{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}
```

Put these redefinitions between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

```
\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \global\booltrue{cbx@seenote}% NEW!
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield[title]{labeltitle}}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%<--- CHANGED
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{\thefield{entrykey}:%
                  \@nameuse{cbx@first@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \printtext{\bibleftparen}%
      \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
      \@nameuse{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \bibstring{page}\addnbspace
      \@nameuse{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:save}{%
  \ifundef\@thefnmark
    {\ifundef\@theenmark % endnotes.sty
       {\csgdef{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}{%
          \BibliographyWarning{Missing footnote mark}\textbf{??}}}
       {\global\cslet{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}\@theenmark}}
    {\global\cslet{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}\@thefnmark}%
  \csxdef{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}{\thepage}%
  \csxdef{cbx@first@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}}
```

We then have the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@incollection{athanasius1998,
    Address = {Berlin/New York},
    Author = {{Athanasius Alexandrinus}},
    Booktitle = {Athanasius Werke - Die dogmatischen Schriften},
    Call-Number = {TH: Vb 17.02-1.1.2},
    Date-Added = {2010-10-16 13:24:30 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-13 17:12:32 +0000},
    Editor = {Marin Tetz and others},
    Keywords = {source},
    Pages = {109-175},
    Publisher = {Walter de Gruyter},
    Read = {No},
    Series = {Urkunden zur Geschichte des Arianischen Streites 318-328},
    Shortauthor = {Ath.},
    Shorttitle = {Ar. 1},
    Title = {Oratio I contra Arianos},
    Volume = {1, Tl. 1, Lfg. 2},
    Year = {1998}}
@incollection{evagrius2011,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {{Evagrius Scholasticus}},
    Booktitle = {{\'E}vagre Le Scholastique: Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique - Livres I-III},
    Call-Number = {TH: Va1.05/542},
    Date-Added = {2013-08-24 12:11:20 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-03-30 11:54:31 +0000},
    Editor = {Joseph Bidez and Leon Parmentier},
    Keywords = {source},
    Publisher = {Les {\'E}ditions du Cerf},
    Series = {Sources chr{\'e}tiennes},
    Shortauthor = {Evagr.},
    Shorttitle = {h.e.},
    Title = {Historia ecclesiastica},
    Volume = {542},
    Year = {2011}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=true, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
%
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx@loccit}%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx@seenote}% NEW!
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:ibid}}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:note}}}
       {\usebibmacro{footcite:shorthand}}}
    {\iffieldundef{usera}
      {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}}
      {\printnames{author}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{title}\isdot%
         {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \usebibmacro{in:}%
          \printfield{usera}%
          \setunit*{\addspace}%
          \printfield[default]{volume}}}%
      \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \global\booltrue{cbx@seenote}% NEW!
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield[title]{labeltitle}}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%<--- CHANGED
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{\thefield{entrykey}:%
                  \@nameuse{cbx@first@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \printtext{\bibleftparen}%
      \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
      \@nameuse{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \bibstring{page}\addnbspace
      \@nameuse{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:save}{%
  \ifundef\@thefnmark
    {\ifundef\@theenmark % endnotes.sty
       {\csgdef{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}{%
          \BibliographyWarning{Missing footnote mark}\textbf{??}}}
       {\global\cslet{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}\@theenmark}}
    {\global\cslet{cbx@note@\thefield{entrykey}}\@thefnmark}%
  \csxdef{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}{\thepage}%
  \csxdef{cbx@first@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 56]{athanasius1998}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 22]{evagrius2011}
\pagebreak
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 11]{athanasius1998}
\blindtext\footcite[See][S. 12]{evagrius2011}
\end{document}
```

The relevant part of the MWE now shows

[image]

Please note that your MWE contains a tiny mistake in `\renewbibmacro*{footcite}`: you are missing a `%` just after the `\printfield[default]{volume}}}}` line.
Also, you should re-arrange the `footcite:save` macro (if it stays where it is in the MWE it will cause `biblatex` to overwrite the page/footnote numbers in certain cases, and we don't want that), so the whole thing becomes

```
\renewbibmacro*{footcite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx@loccit}%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx@seenote}% NEW!
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:ibid}}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:note}}}
       {\usebibmacro{footcite:shorthand}}}
    {\iffieldundef{usera}
      {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}}
      {\printnames{author}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{title}\isdot%
         {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \usebibmacro{in:}%
          \printfield{usera}%
          \setunit*{\addspace}%
          \printfield[default]{volume}}}%
      \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}%
}
```

Comment: This does indeed work on the MWE and thank you for that! Unfortunately when I tried to integrate this to my work I realised that I should have mentioned the reason why I want to achieve this in the first place. I need footnote numbers to start new with each session (otherwise I will endue with four digit numbers in the footnotes). Thats why the old (wie Anm. X) was not enough because this number belongs to some other chapter now.

Comment: Anyway I achieved this by adding \usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{footnote}{section} which does what I want except that it also affects the solution you gave me here so that number of footnote shows the first occurrence of that quote only within one section not within the whole work. I realise this sounds very complicated and I don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: Should I modify mo original my original MWE to illustrate what I am talking here or should I make a completely new topic for this? And thanks for your help!

Comment: @eklisiarh Please have a look at the edited answer, it seems to me that the problem is fixed.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for your help!!!